# Django UpdateView: AttributeError: not able to access forms.Form data -> type object 'EventSingleAttendeeForm' has no attribute 'attendee_name'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

## views.py

```
class EventUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventUpdateForm
    second_form_class= EventSingleAttendeeForm
    template_name = 'events/event_update.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.creator = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        event = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == event.creator:
            return True
        return False

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['form2'] = self.second_form_class
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            event_data = form.save(commit=False)
            # attendee_name = form2.attendee_name
            if form2.attendee_name != '' and form2.attendee_email != '' and form2.attendee_mobile:
                attendee = Attendee(name=form2.attendee_name, email=form2.attendee_email, mobile=form2.attendee_mobile)
                existing_attendee = Attendee.objects.filter(Q(email__exact=form2.attendee_email) | Q(mobile__exact=form2.attendee_mobile))
                if existing_attendee:
                    attendee = existing_attendee.first()
                else:
                    attendee.save()
                form.attendees.add(attendee)
            form.save()
            return redirect('some')
```

## forms.py

```
class EventSingleAttendeeForm(forms.Form):
    attendee_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    attendee_mobile = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    attendee_email = forms.EmailField(required=False)



builtins.AttributeError
AttributeError: type object 'EventSingleAttendeeForm' has no attribute 'attendee_name'
```

I am getting this error I want to access the data in those fields but I am not able to. A little help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `form.is_valid()`, you can access the form's data from its `cleaned_data`.

```
if form2.cleaned_data['attendee_name'] != '' and form2.cleaned_data['attendee_email' != '' and form2.cleaned_data['attendee_mobile']:
```

Or, if it's a model form, you can use the instance that is returned by `form.save()`, or use `form.instance`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the fields to the Meta class? like this:

```
class EventSingleAttendeeForm(forms.Form):
    attendee_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    attendee_mobile = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    attendee_email = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'attendee_name',
            'attendee_mobile',
            'attendee_email'
        )
```

Comment: TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
in super(EventUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)   
any help will be appreciated